# How to change the number of iterations of a for-loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have the following question: when using a for loop, the number of iterations is initially fixed but is it possible to make it change at each loop?

For example I run a matrix M (30x2)

```
    for i = 1: size (M, 1)
    Bla bla bla
    M = [M; BLA bla]
    end
```

So in this case the matrix M changes size at each loop (or almost depending on the conditions) and I want this change to be taken into account in the number of iterations `i`.

I tried this: (but it's not working)

```
L=length(M);
for i = 1:L
Bla bla bla
M = [M; BLA bla]
L=L+1; or I tried too L=length(M);
end
```

Comment: You need a `while`, not a `for`, so that the loop condition is dynamically evaluated after each iteration, taking into account the updated matrix

Comment: `for i = 1:L` is compiled as `for each [1,2,... L]`, so it is not dynamic within the loop. Typically if you want to have a conditionally-sized loop, you should `while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one option:

```
i = 1;
while i ~= N
    etc...
    i = i+1;
    N = size(M,2); %or whatever
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase the iterations of for loop, but you can use if statement inside for loop and break earlier:

```
for i = 1: size (M, 1)
    Bla bla bla
    M = [M; BLA bla]
    if size(M,1)>10, break; end % use your condition to stop
end
```

Comment: How does breaking _earlier_ work, when the matrix is being _grown_ within the loop?

Comment: Oh, breaking earlier won't apply here, unless to preset a huge number of iterations. In that case, while loop should be better anyway.